# Tetris - Hard drop Logic

Tags: java

I'm building tetris and am confused as to how I can make a piece hard drop.

I tried adding a `hardDrop()` method to Board class which would iterate from the bottom row and check for open spaces...

Board class:

```
public int hardDrop() {
    int hardDropRow = 0;
    for(int row = totalRows-1; row > 0; row--) {
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] != null) {
                hardDropRow = row;
                return hardDropRow;
            }
        }       
    }
    return hardDropRow;
}
```

Piece class:

Then here, for each piece I would add the valid `dropRow` to the `getRow()`:

```
        //Hard drop
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            //get next valid coordinates nearest to bottom 
            //hard drop needs to which row the piece needs to drop to
            int dropRow;
            dropRow = board.hardDrop();
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow()+dropRow, tile[i].getCol(), i);
            }
```

When I press up, the piece just seems to skip down a few rows even though the whole bottom is null... so it should just move to that spot.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT --**

I've updated my timer so it accepts a value... if `val == 1`, that means instant drop was hit... so it sets the interval = 10 milliseconds...

If `val != 1`, it goes through the case statement.

For some reason, once `timer(1)` is set, the interval won't change back even if I change it...

**Board class:**

```
public void timer (int val) {
    int interval;
    if (val == 1) {
        interval = 1;       
    }
    else {
        switch (level) {
        //each level increases drop speed by .10 seconds
            case 1: interval = 700;
                    break;
            case 2: interval = 600;
                    break;
            case 3: interval = 500;
                    break;
            case 4: interval = 400;
                    break;
            case 5: interval = 300;
                    break;
            default: interval = 800;
                    break;
        }
    }
    Timer t = new Timer(interval, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (pause && gameWon){
                message = "You've won!";
            }
            else if (pause) {               
                seconds++;
            }
            else {
                seconds = 0;
                newPiece.autoMove();
                repaint(); 
            }
        }
     });
    t.start();  
}
```

**Piece class:** You see that I send `1` as a parameter to `timer()` for the hard drop...
Then set it back with something other than `1`...

```
    //hard drop
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        board.timer(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow()+1, tile[i].getCol(), i);
        }
        clearCurrPosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            board.checkEndGame(tile[i].getRow(), tile[i].getCol());
        }
        board.timer(0);
        board.checkBottomFull();
        if (isCollision()) board.createNewPiece();
        move();
```

Comment: Why not just move the piece down row by row until there is a collision?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `return hardDropRow` so you can see where it fails?

Comment: your hard drop function should do the same exact thing that your game timer does, drop the current piece until there is a collision.  The hard drop function should just perform the "tick" very fast, ignoring the timer's speed

Comment: Is it valid to add dropRow - which is an absolute coordinate I think - to the current row? In hard drop if you're checking for empty spaces do you really mean != null? And shouldn't it depend on the shape, rotation and current column of the current piece?

Comment: @binnyb lol oh... I guess I was overthinking it :/

Comment: @mbeckish I've updated the code above

Comment: All you show about `interval` is that it is a local variable in the `timer` method.  You don't show how it is used to control the speed of individual pieces moving down the screen.

Comment: @mbeckish updated the code above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tetris is a game which doesn't require collision management, *per se*, because everything is constrained to a grid, and you can always get the coordinates of populated squares. Some Tetris variants implement an 'instant drop,' in which a press of the 'down' button ('up,' in your case) will instantly place the current piece wherever it would land on the bottom. Personally, I favor the other option, which is to speed up (significantly, to a point) the drop speed of the piece.

Either way, I would recommend calling a `setFinalPosition()` method every time the piece is moved (sideways or rotated), which would store the location of the current piece, should the user take no action or drop the piece. Then, if you want to do an 'instant drop,' you can just call `getFinalPosition()` and place the piece there. You could also use the `getFinalPosition()` method whenever a piece moves even *without* user action, and just check to see if the current position equals the final position. If it does, stop the piece.

Note that whether or not you bother with collisions, looking ahead to where the piece would end up in an absence of user action (or if the user drops the piece) is the way to go.